# How to do change the value in the class with the help of method in C#

Tags: c#, object, methods

### I want to call an object from a different class and change its properties.

I want to get into this object and make changes.

But when I type the dot, the properties do not open.

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SINIF3 sınıf3 = new SINIF3();

//I want to get into this object and make changes.
//But when I type the dot, the properties do not open.
//For example
//sınıf3.gonder(1).number=2;

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
    class DEGER
    {
        public int number = 1;
    }
    class SINIF3
    {
        public object gonder(int a)
        {
            DEGER objem = new DEGER();
            DEGER objem2 = new DEGER();
            if (a == 1)
                return objem;
            else return objem2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this is just sample code, but your `SINIF3.gonder()` method can be reduced to: `public DEGER gonder() { return new DEGER(); }`

Answer (score 1):

Change the return type of the gonder method from object to DEGER.  Of course you're not assigning the result of the gonder method to a variable, so the new object which you change the number field in will be thrown away.

Answer (score 0):

Change the the method.

from         public object gonder(int a)

to         public DEGER gonder(int a)

otherwise you need to cast the object 
something like 
sınıf3.((DEGER )gonder(1)).number=2;

But you should try not to return object if you can.